# Einstein notation in Electrodynamics

Tags: electromagnetism, tensor-calculus, notation

I have a question about the notation used in Electrodynamics, for the Eq.6.5.10. Can anyone tell me why is the sign of the covariant derivative swapped when it's transformed to a contravariant derivative? But it doesn't change for index zero. Many Thanks .

[image]

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the simplest explanation is the one given in the picture above. Starting from Maxwell's equation in vector form you realise that you can treat them as coming from a more general object (cf. [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/156090/how-are-plane-waves-p-forms-and-maxwells-equations-related/)). As for the derivatives, observe that $\partial^\mu = g^{\mu\nu}\partial_\nu = (\partial_0, -\partial_1,-\partial_2-\partial_3)$.

Comment: Many Thanks... I should have figured this out... But not familiar with these notations!